# A function for items in select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want use a function that returns me a array of object and use it as a item for vuetify select.

I also use it like this :

```
<v-select
     :items='functionToCall()'
     ......
>
```

I I console log the const after the function , I have the output that I want, but nothing in my select menu.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the actual function to be called to the vue markup, and not actually calling it. You need to call the function like so:

```js
<v-select
     :items='functionToCall()'
     ......
>
```

However, it's preferred that you use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), as a function call will only be invoked when the component re-renders. A computed property will update reactively based on the reactive data that generate its output.

ETA: And AFAIK, the only reliable way to force a component, or part of a component to re-render is by changing the [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component) prop of the component. Other than that `$forceUpdate` and other methods don't seem to reliably force a re-render (and you shouldn't have to force a re-render in most cases anyways, if you do, you're probably doing something wrong)

Comment: Oh I make a type, I call it like this sorry

Comment: Then try using a computed property. Using a function call within the template for anything other than an event can be problematic (because functions are only called once the component is rendered. So if your data isn't already ready when the component is rendered, that will cause you to be stuck with an empty value for `items` until a re-render happens)

Answer (score 0):

The function that will return your array of objects should be a computed property and you could use it like so:

```
<v-select
    v-model="computedProperty"
    item-text="title"
    item-value="id"
></v-select>
...
computed: {
    computedProperty(){
        * your code here where you form the array *
        return array
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you really need to pass something to the function, you can use the same function in methods like so:

```
methods: {
    computedProperty(passedInfo){
        * your code here where you form the array with passedInfo *
        return array
    }
}
```